# Regular Expression using vbscript for two numbers: not valid:"$123456789012" and valid: "12345678912"

Tags: regex, vbscript

I wanted to create regular Expression to find the number with 10 or more digits and that number should not have `$` symbol in front of it.

Eg:
not valid:`$123456789012` and valid: `12345678912`.

Apart from this I have more validations for example finding number pattern: 3digits - 4digits, 3digits - 4digits - 5digits.

But for now I am able to create pattern for all those but unable to do for `$<number>`, could you please help.

Sorry for not mentioning in the beginning - this is using vbscript.

Code:

```
RegularExpressionObject.IgnoreCase = True 
RegularExpressionObject.Global = True 
RegularExpressionObject.Pattern =
    "(([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5})|([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}-[‌​0-9]{6})|([0-9]{10}))"
    'pattern:CCID or 3(digits)-4(digits), 3(digits)-4(digits)-5(digits), 3(digits)-4(digits)-5(digits)-6(digits), 10digts and above number 
Set Matches = RegularExpressionObject.Execute(Rescomts)
    If (Matches.Count <> 0) Then
```

In the above code, regular expression pattern 10 digits are allowed, but I wanted to ignore 10 digits starting from `$` symbol

Comment: What pattern have you created?

Comment: +1 MxyL, the current pattern could help finding the problem. Plus `$` could be a character to escape.

Comment: [`(?<!\$)\b\d{10,}`](http://regex101.com/r/oB1xZ2) -- use a negative lookahead to assert that there isn't a `$` before matching your digits. I threw a word boundary in there to clean up some of the matches.

Comment: That's a negative look behind, but still correct otherwise.

Comment: @adamdc78, ugh I always do that. Thanks :)

Comment: @Srekk, please specify the regex language you wish to use. Javascript accepts different formats than PCRE, and can sometimes limit use of some features (like regex look-around).

Comment: Hi All, sorry for not mentioning the language. I would need this in Vbscript.

Answer (score 3):

As @Sam said, you would probably use a negative look-behind:

```
(?<!\$)\b[0-9]{10,}\b
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/vR3iF6

Depending on the language selected, look-around may not be available. For example, Javascript limits the use of `(?<!\$)` so you may need to write it as

```
[^$]\b[0-9]{10,}\b
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/oH5uE4

Some languages support `\d`, which may make your regex look cleaner. Others don't, and you'll need to write `[0-9]`.

**EDIT**
Per @AlanMoore's suggestion, extraneous characters may also interfere. You might be able to get around this by using `\b[^$]\b` instead of just a single `\b`:

```
\b[^$]\b[0-9]{10,}\b
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/lL2bN9

This would get rid of preceding spaces, non-digit characters, etc.

Comment: Guess I should've posted this as an answer..the other two are pretty subpar, +1 thanks for the credit.

Comment: In your second regex, I think you'd want `\b[^$]?\d{10,}\b` since there's no requirement that there be a character there, only that there cannot be a `$` there and it would be within the same word boundary.  Unfortunately this will could also allow some invalid edge cases, depending on the OP's needs.

Comment: @adamdc78: Try using your regex in the 2nd example. If any of the TEST STRING lines light up in blue, it's a match, which is what the OP wants to avoid. If it works (no blue), then I can update my answer.

Comment: You're right!  `$` isn't going to be part of a word boundary because it's not a word character.  This brings up other issues, however, of other non-word characters (such as a space) being valid and potentially showing up in the input.  Your regex was quite correct and you have my apologies.

Comment: No, @adamdc78 is right.  In your test, the `[^$]` is matching the linefeed preceding the `1234567890` line; put that on the first line and you'll see it doesn't match.  For JavaScript, you'd need to use `(?:^|[^$])`.

Comment: @AlanMoore: What about prepending `\b` to the `[^$]` ?

Comment: Not quite @OnlineCop: `a!0123456789`.

Comment: If I could guarantee that the number appears that the beginning of the line, I'd just write `^[0-9]{10,}\b` but the OP doesn't indicate that this is the case.

Comment: Thanks guys, but can you please give me solution in Vbscript.

Comment: @Srekk: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms974570.aspx indicates that it accepts most of the regex depicted here. If it gives you an error, post the error messages (or partial results, or whatever) so we know what we need to do to modify it. Having sample text helps quite a bit.

Comment: sure @OnlineCop, thanks for letting me know. Here is the sample code:

Comment: Code:
RegularExpressionObject.IgnoreCase = True
RegularExpressionObject.Global = True
RegularExpressionObject.Pattern = "(([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4})|([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5})|([0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{5}-[0-9]{6})|([0-9]{10}))" 'pattern:CCID or 3(digits)-4(digits), 3(digits)-4(digits)-5(digits), 3(digits)-4(digits)-5(digits)-6(digits), 10digts and above number
Set Matches = RegularExpressionObject.Execute(Rescomts)
If (Matches.Count <> 0) Then
--
--
 In the above code, regular expression pattern 10 digits are allowed, but i wanted to ignore 10 digits starting from $ symbol.

Comment: @Srekk: You probably want to edit your original post with this code so everyone can see it without wading through comments.

Answer (score 0):

This regular expression seems to work:

```
^[^\$][0-9]{9,}$
```

Comment: More specifically, I made a test file containing these strings on new lines: 1234; 123456789012; $123456789012; $123. And I did egrep "^[^\$][0-9]{10,}$" ./testfilename, which returned only 123456789012.

Comment: That will fail on a 10 digit number because it has to have a non-$ character before the 10+ digits.

Comment: @adamdc78, you are correct, sir. The edited regex work now, I think.

Comment: But, it will "find the number with ten or more digits" and not anything with a "$" in front of it...

Comment: ` 123456789` is only 9 digits.  It also relies on the number being the entirety of the input.  The answer provided by Sam in the comments on the question uses the negative lookbehind and word boundaries rather than start and end of input to provide a more reliable solution.

Comment: As pointed out, some edge cases may sneak in with this regex (example: http://regex101.com/r/aM7iL5).

Comment: @adamdc78, it will not accept 123456789, dude check yo stuff

Comment: It will accept ` 123456789` (space then 123456789).

Comment: Also, since it accepts newlines, it will accept `123456789` preceeded by a newline as shown here [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/jD8eL8).  For some reason it won't keep the leading newline on the save, so you'll have to manually go in and hit enter in order to get it to match.

Comment: Hi Guys, can you please give me reg ex in vbscript. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any vbscript skills